# Wordpress plugin (Ultimate Member) still calls localhost after changing wordpress url

Tags: php, css, wordpress

This is kind of a follow up question to my last post.

I've installed a WordPress site locally on my laptop and now, after some initital problems, I can finally access that site from my PC in the same local network. At first it did not display CSS, only HTML, so I changed the WordPress address (URL) to `http://my-host-ip/my-website`, which worked just fine.

But now, when I login, the Ultimate Member Profile won't show, I think because it is still trying to call `localhost`. Even in the WordPress admin Firefox is trying to reach localhost. And when I view the sites source I get calls like:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost/hp1/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg"/>
```

or

```
</span><img onerror="this.src='http://localhost/hp1/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg';"  src="http://localhost/hp1/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg" class="func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-100 um-avatar um-avatar-default" width="100"  height="100" alt="Erika Musterfrau" /></a>
```

I would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to fix that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if you have any cache plugin, cloudfare, save permalinks, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old link that exists in your sql db , You should search and replace all these links with the new urls matching to your current website url , I Prefer using SEARCH-REPLACE-DB-MASTER tool , But don't forget to delete it right after its usage , Plus also you may find some broken links "posts/pages" , Don't worry , This just need you to open your dashboard "Settings - Permalinks - Save" so that you reset your permalinks , Here is the tool and its documentation . https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Even though I did it more or less by hand (phpmyadmin).

Comment: You are welcome , changing records by hand using phpmyadmin can't work for big number of rows ,so you it is better to use this tool but don't forget to delete it .